# How do I interface with Amcharts from outside chart creation functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I create an amchart, and in creation I set the hidden value of one of the data sets to true:

```
function loadChart(container, chartstodisplay) {

    AmCharts.ready(function () {
        //Do all my regular chart creation here

        //but make sure hidechart shows up hidden
        if(key == 'hidechart'){
            graphs[key].hidden = true;
        }                           

        //now write the chart
        chart.write(container);
    });
}
```

Now here I am later in my page, and I have some html that is associated with the chart etc. For example, I have a link that if you hover over, I want "hidechart" to now be visible, please realize this functionality is completely separate from the legend blocks that AMcharts creates that you can click to hide/unhide, this is separate on page html.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#some_parent').on('click','span.unhide',function(){
        //now go back to the hidden chart element from above and change
        graph['hidechart'].hidden = false;
        //obviously that doesn't work
     })

})
```

So is there any context in which I can reach and influence the charts and graphs? How do I have to approach this?

Answer (score 7):

You don't really provide enough code to work with, for instance how you're adding the graphs but I think I can help if I make some assumptions.

I assume you have an array of graphs that you're adding to the chart, first make sure the graphs array and chart object are global, so outside the functions (i.e. before `loadChart`) declare them:

```
var chart;
var graphs;
```

Then follow the advice from the [documentation](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph) on `hidden`:

> Specifies whether the graph is hidden. Do not use this to show/hide the graph, use hideGraph(graph) and showGraph(graph) methods instead.

The documenation for `showGraph` and `hideGraph` is [here](http://docs.amcharts.com/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart).

So you need to update your hide routine to be (after you've added the graph):

```
 //but make sure hidechart shows up hidden
     if (key == 'hidechart'){
     chart.hideGraph(graphs[key]);
 }
```

Finally you can show that by accessing the two global objects:

```
 $('#some_parent').on('click','span.unhide',function(){
     //now go back to the hidden chart element from above and change
     chart.showGraph(graphs['hidechart']);
     //should work now
 })
```

I've tested that locally and it works, if that doesn't help consider posting a little more code or creating a jsFiddle as an example. Also check out [this answer](http://www.amcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=30518) from the forums.

Answer (score 0):

First when I get this question,I try many times to solve it,but it can't help.
Finally I get it take a look into below image.

[image]

```
graph.hidden = true;
chart.addGraph(graph);
```

This is also help,but it will be slowly

```
chart.write("chartdiv");
chart.hideGraph(graph)
```